# Android : transform Classes With Multidexlist For Debug Exception

Tags: android, exception, gradle, android-multidex

I have updated my android studio to Android 3.1.1 and after updating i have tried to run my app but it is giving me the `app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug` exception.

i have tried the following things to resolve the error 1.

1. clean and rebuild

   2.Added the multidex support

   3.invalidate caches and restart

   4.changed the compiledVersion to 21

But the error is still coming. I am posting this question bcoz i m now left with zero options please help me to get rid of this Error.

```
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
41 actionable tasks: 38 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

**app level gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lenovo.jdstudio"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':sdkuii')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        //noinspection GradleCompatible

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'

        //glide library
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

        //firebase support library
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

        //firebase-UI support library
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'

        //CardView and RecyclerView library
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

        //Image cropper
//        implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'

        //Butter knife
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail
        //implementation group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.1'
//        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
//        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
//        compile files('libs/mail.jar')

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.lenovo.jdstudio">

    <!-- Permission for CropImageTool -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Permission for Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <!--android:name=".JDStudio"-->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/JDStudioTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/JDStudioTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- CropImageActivity -->
        <!--<activity-->
            <!--android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"-->
            <!--android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />-->

        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SetupActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UserMainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AdminMainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".IndividualProduct" />
        <activity android:name=".ShoppingCartWindow" />
        <activity android:name=".SchedulingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UpdateOrderStatusActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**progurg-rules.pro**

```
-keep class com.example.lenovo.jdstudio
```

Comment: Enable offline gradle and disable instant run and then rebuild. There is no logic in it but this worked for me when i got this error in past. So, you can give a try to it.

Comment: ty for your words but this doesn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the Error by following steps

**1.Deleted the unused files from my project

2.clean

3.Rebuild**

and boom the project runs...